# Pull coefficients from a data frame based on information in another data frame

Tags: r

Right now I have two data frames in R, contains some data that looks like this:

```
> data
  p a         i
1 1 1 2.2561469
2 5 2 0.2316390
3 2 3 0.4867456
4 3 1 0.1511705
5 4 2 0.8838884
```

And one the contains coefficients that looks like this:

```
> coef
         3        2        1
1 29420.50 31029.75 29941.96
2 26915.00 27881.00 27050.00
3 27756.00 28904.00 28699.40
4 28345.33 29802.33 28377.56
5 28217.00 29409.00 28738.67
```

These data frames are connected as each value in data$a corresponds to a column name in coef and data$p corresponds to row names in coef.

I need to apply these coefficients to multiply these coefficients by the values in data$i by matching the row and column names in coef to data$a and data$p.

In other words, for each row in data, I need to use data$a and data$p for each row to pull a specific number from coef that will be multiplied by the value of data$i for that row to create a new vector in data that looks something like this:

```
> data
  p a         i          z
1 1 1 2.2561469      67553
2 5 2 0.2316390       6812
3 2 3 0.4867456         .
4 3 1 0.1511705         .
5 4 2 0.8838884         .
```

I was thinking I should create factors in my coef data frame based on the row and column names but am unsure of where to go from there.

Thanks in advance,

Ian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you order your `coef` data.frame, you can just index them as though the column names weren't there.

```
coef <- coef[,order(names(coef))]
```

Then `apply` a function to each row:

```
myfun <- function(x) {
  x[3]*coef[x[1], x[2]]
}

data$z <- apply(data, 1, myfun)

> data
  p a         i         z
1 1 1 2.2561469 67553.460
2 5 2 0.2316390  6812.271
3 2 3 0.4867456 13100.758
4 3 1 0.1511705  4338.503
5 4 2 0.8838884 26341.934
>
```